# getting error when typing p into double?

Tags: java

When typing p into the scanner when it prompts for an operator, ex. 1, 2, 3 or 4, I am getting an error message. The rest of the code goes through but I am wondering how I can make it to where you may enter, for example, a p, and get looped back to it prompting your for the correct operator

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class charlespeppersprog5 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner operand = new Scanner (System.in);
        double leftOperand = 0;
        double rightOperand = 0;
        double operator = 0;
        double finalAnswer = 0;

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Enter the left operand : ");
        leftOperand = operand.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the right operand : ");
        rightOperand = operand.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("\t 1 -> Multiplication");
        System.out.println("\t 2 -> Division");
        System.out.println("\t 3 -> Addition");
        System.out.println("\t 4 -> Subtraction");

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Choose an operator from the above menu : ");
        operator = operand.nextDouble();
            while (operator!=1 && operator!=2 && operator!=3 && operator!=4)
            {
            System.out.print("Choose an operator from the above menu : ");
                operator = operand.nextDouble();
            }
```

`enter code here`// right here the example asks to loop again if any is entered in besides `enter code here`1,2,3,4. so enter p and you get this message
`enter code here`//Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at charlespeppersprog5.main(charlespeppersprog5.java:35)

```
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        if (operator==1)
        {
        finalAnswer = (leftOperand * rightOperand);
        System.out.println(rightOperand + " * " + leftOperand + " = " + finalAnswer);
        }

        if (operator==2)
        {
            finalAnswer = (leftOperand / rightOperand);
            System.out.println(rightOperand + " / " + leftOperand + " = " + finalAnswer);
        }

        if (operator==3)
        {
            finalAnswer = (leftOperand + rightOperand);
            System.out.println(rightOperand + " + " + leftOperand + " = " + finalAnswer);
        }

        if (operator==4)
        {
            finalAnswer = (leftOperand - rightOperand);
            System.out.println(rightOperand + " - " + leftOperand + " = " + finalAnswer);
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        operand.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Post the error please!

Comment: -----------------------------------------


Enter the left operand : 1.2

Enter the right operand : 3.4


-----------------------------------------


  1 -> Multiplication
  2 -> Division
  3 -> Addition
  4 -> Subtraction

-----------------------------------------


Choose an operator from the above menu : p

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at charlespeppersprog5.main(charlespeppersprog5.java:35)

Comment: @user3316886: please add it to your question not as a comment!

Comment: you can see where i entered p and it gives me the error immediately

Comment: so enter a value between 1 and 4

Answer (score 1):

This is because it expects a double and gets something else. Check for the double first.

```
while (!operand.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 - 4");
    operand.next(); // accept anything but exit while loop when conditions are met
} 
operator  = operand.nextDouble() ;
```

Comment: @user3316886 This code will work. Please remember to upvote and mark this answer as correct if it helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You will receive an error because the compiler is ecpecting a double value but is receiving an invalid argument and is likely throwing something kind of an exception. You can include the code where you want to check the input type in a try/catch block as follows:

```
try {
    operator = operand.nextDouble();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) { // Note you are only catching invalid input. Other double values will still be accepted
    flag = false;
}
if (flag) {
    // do logic
} else {
    // go back
}
```

I hope you get the general idea on how to solve it. I just showed a very simple logic for you - you can implement it however you need.